# How to connect to SQL Server running on top of Amazon EC2

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect remotely to my amazon ec2 msssql intance.

I'm locally (via RD) connecting to it using Management Studio.
This is the only option it popped up under Local Servers -> Databse Engine on the "Connect to Server" menu

[image]

Surprisingly, when I ping to the Striked trough domain, I get a reply from a PRIVATE IP.

So dear amazon and friends: Where can I get the public IP for the database server? 
 Why your Windows + SQL Server installation image is configured to point to a different server other that the one that I connect via RD.

Am I missing anything? What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The public IP address for your SQL server is the public IP address that is assigned to the EC2 instance. You will see this when you look at your EC2 instance details in the AWS Management Console. The public IP will be either:

- the auto-assigned IP address, or
- an Elastic IP address

Internally, the EC2 instance only sees the private IP address. It does not know about the public IP address. That is why when you ping the server name, it resolves to the internal IP address.

If you want to connect to your SQL server remotely, you need to do the following:

1. Open port 1433 to your local, internet-facing IP address
2. Connect to the SQL server by it's public IP address
3. Double check that your SQL server has TCP/IP connections enabled. Often it's disabled by default

Comment: Not working... I'm trying to telnet into serverIP:1433  (being serverIp, the same IP that I connect via RD) and I get nothing. 

It's like nothing is listening on 1433. What could I do?

Comment: Double check that your SQL server has TCP/IP connections enabled. Often it's disabled by default.

Comment: Hi there, Not working... I'm running an ec2 instance with Windows Server.
I added a rule in the Firewall to open that port 1433 and I enabled the SQL server TCP/IP connections, algo the Security Group has in the inbound rules the 1433 open for anywhere.
I'm trying to connecte via DBeaver
@MattHouser

Comment: Similar answer here and it works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/26809741/1721946